# terraform remove specific resource by id

Tags: terraform

When i run `terraform apply` it creates a droplet on digitalOcean, and soon as it creates, i I am removing the `terrafrom.tfstate` file and all the file that created after droplet luanch. and i am saving that info in a database.

Now i want to delete certain resource by its resource id or urn or uuid. is it possible?

I am saving these info in database.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots, but use properly formatted code blocks.

Comment: If you get rid of `terrafrom.tfstate`, what's even the point of using TF in the first place?

Comment: then how can i create multiple `terrafrom.tfstate` ? coz, it doesnt allow create new if there is already one

Comment: @anamul hello did you spot an error with my answer after all? Since you unapproved it. Do you mind sharing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the tf state, you should just **copy** it to the database

Then to remove a specific resource

```
terraform destroy -target TYPE.NAME
```

In your case

```
terraform destroy -target digitalocean_droplet.web
```